# Nginx not available from localhost, but available by network

Tags: php, nginx

Have server with installed nginx and php-fpm. Some sctript need access to part of site via curl. But it fails. I tried to run curl on server :

```
curl -v -i alexcoder.info
* About to connect() to alexcoder.info port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 88.198.156.238...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

But from network sites available :

```
curl -v -i alexcoder.info
* Rebuilt URL to: alexcoder.info/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x702b10
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x702b10) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to alexcoder.info port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 88.198.156.238...
* Connected to alexcoder.info (88.198.156.238) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: alexcoder.info
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

nginx logs does not contain any errors aboout this. I tried to flush iptables rules but it take no effect.

What it may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Multiple servers

You need to setup a listener for each network interface you want Nginx to respond to:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

You likely already have a `server {..}` section that's listening on the actual interface that your system binds to when it gets an IP address.

#### Multiple listeners

You can also add multiple `Listen` lines to a `server {..}` section like so:

#### Examples

```
listen     *:80;
```

or

listen     localhost:80;
listen     127.0.0.1:80;
listen     12.34.56.78:80;

I would likely do it using this second method! See this article for more examples, titled: - [Basic Nginx Configuration](https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic).

#### References

- [Server Names - Nginx Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
- [Server Block Examples](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample)
- [NGINX multiple server blocks with reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902727/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-with-reverse-proxy)
- [Basic Nginx Configuration](https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic)

Comment: @alexgauss1994 - yup, thanks for the Q!